# How to add data to realative table laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have model Object with relationship:

```
 public function category(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\FieldCategoriesValues');
 }
```

How to add new value to category?

I tried:

```
$object = new Object();
$object->category()->save(["id" => 4])
```

It does not work.

Comment: You should probably use the `create()` method instead of `save()` for saving directly from an assoc array - as described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save the relationship the first model needs to be created before creating/saving the second model.  You can check for existence of a mode with the `$exists` attribute.

Also, you pass a model to a relationship's `save()` method and an array to `create()`.

For example for the parent model:

```
$object = new Object;
$object->exists; // false
$object->save();
$object->exists; // true
```

**OR**

```
$object = Object::create();
$object->exists; // true
```

Then you can save the related model as:

```
$category = new Category(["id" => 4]);
$object->category()->save($category);
```

**OR**

```
$category = $object->category()->create(["id" => 4]);
```

Comment: Can I delete like as: `$category = $object->category()->delete(["id" => 4]);`

Comment: Since you're working with a `hasOne` relationship `$object->category` will return a model so you can do `$object->category->delete();`